# Gradle error :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

i tring to run my app but the gradle give me this error

> :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED Error:Execution
>   failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/inject/Inject.class
> >     Information:BUILD FAILED

this my AndroidMainifist.xml

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mohamed.movieapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.22.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.22.1'
}


repositories {
    maven { url 'java.lang.android.support.v7.app.WindowDecoreActionBar' }
}
```

can any one help please

Answer (score 0):

The duplication comes from jersey client. It depends on both `org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject` and `javax.inject:javax.inject`.
So, you need to exclude one of them:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile ('org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.22.1') {
        exclude group: 'javax.inject', module: 'javax.inject'
    }
    ...
}
```

I try to use `org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy` in my project and had to apply the same exclusion for that dependency too - likely it will be the same for `org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson`.